# Reference error when attempting to build/link project with mingw-w64

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to build my program and have been getting errors that I don't know how to resolve.

The errors are `undefined reference to '__security_init_cookie'` and `undefined reference to '__mingw_init_ehandler'`. I suspect it's something to do with linking but I am unsure how to solve this, I found no real resolutions on google.

My compilation args are below with the relevant error:

**Compilation:**

```
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\WAMsoft.exe 
@object_script.WAMsoft.Debug  -LC:\boost_1_75_0\boost -LC:\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-
w64-mingw32\sys-root\mingw\lib -L\usr\include -Xlinker --verbose -w -lgmp -lm -
LC:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib 
C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib\libQt5Widgetsd.a 
C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib\libQt5Guid.a 
C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib\libQt5Xmld.a 
C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib\libQt5XmlPatternsd.a 
C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib\libQt5Networkd.a 
C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-build\qtbase\lib\libQt5Cored.a  "C:\Program 
Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-
mingw32\lib\libglu32.a" "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-
rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libopengl32.a" "C:\Program Files\mingw-
w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" 
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-
mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" -lmingw32 C:\Users\ChrisFusco\Documents\QT\qt5-
build\qtbase\lib\libqtmaind.a -lshell32
```

**Full Error:**

```
attempt to open C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/crtend.o succeeded
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/crtend.o
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x264): undefined reference to `__mingw_init_ehandler'      
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x4c2): undefined reference to `__security_init_cookie'     
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x4f2): undefined reference to `__security_init_cookie'     
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help is very much appreciated; I've been at this for days and I just want to move on to coding!

Comment: Does it work for you with a simple Hello World program?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems has happened to me before. When the following message shows, the problem usually would be the static library is not found

> undefined reference to `....`

My suggestion would be why not move your static libraries ".a" into the folder

```
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/
```